# Probability that exactly 3 people from a classroom of 25 people has the same birth month.

Tags: probability

This was a multiple-choice question, with the answers as intervals. The choices were (P is the probability):

$P = 0\\
0 < P < 0.3 \\
0.3 \le P< 0.7 \\
0.7 \le P < 1 \\
P = 1 \\$

What first came into my mind is that I checked the question using the pigeonhole principle, which states that for 12 months, if there are 25 people in the room, then there must be at least a month that has 3 people contained in it (in the meaning of there will always be a month where at least 3 people share the same birthday). Hence, $P=1$ if the question asks for 'at least 3 people'.

But, it kinda feels off for 'exactly 3 people' because what if there's a possibility where like, all the people have the same birthday? Or, what if it goes like January has 10, February has 10, and March has 5, which means there are no months that contains 3 people having a birthday at that month? In my logic, it kind of contradicts the answer that $P=1$.

Is there a thing about pigeonhole principle that I don't know, like, each container must be filled evenly first?

Comment: @user Is it true if I say that probability is zero because if I spread it evenly, there will at least be a month that has 3 people in it if there are 25 people? But, by my understanding, 1 is the answer if the question asks for 'probability AT LEAST that 3 people have the same birth month'. This question asks, however, 'probability that EXACTLY 3 people have the same birth month,' which I don't understand.

Comment: $1$ is indeed the probability if we are talking about *at least*.  The question where we ask about *at least* is sooo common that there should be no doubt about whether or not this was what was intended as the question.  This makes the question about pigeonhole principle and makes the answer immediate since $\lceil \frac{25}{12}\rceil = 3$ there is clearly at least one month who has at least three people out of our 25 having been born in that month.

Comment: Now... if you really do want to ask about what the probability is that we get a month who has *exactly* three people born in it and not more than three... we need to ask what distribution it follows.  The distribution didn't matter for the version of the question where we asked 'at least' but it matters for this problem where we have 'exactly'.  It becomes a tedious question too, likely relying on inclusion-exclusion.  If we were to assume each month is equally likely (*not a good assumption since feb has fewer days and human habits actually make certain months more likely*) then...

Comment: ...without proof the probability that at least one month has exactly three people born in it would be something like $\dfrac{12\binom{25}{3}11^{22}-\binom{12}{2}\binom{25}{3}\binom{22}{3}10^{19}+\binom{12}{3}\binom{25}{3}\binom{22}{3}\binom{19}{3}9^{16}-\dots}{12^{25}}$

Comment: Your intuition is correct, the answer is not $P=1$. It is asking about exactly, not 'at least'.

Answer (score 1):

If one assumes that the words "exactly three people" mean that there is only one triplet of people such that all three are born in the same month, then the probability of this event is: 
$$\frac{12\frac{25!}{3!(2!)^{11}}}{12^{25}}\approx 0.000016,$$
where the numerator counts the number of combinations with 3 birthdays in one month and 2 birthdays in each of remaining 11 months.